# How to replace all values of a MysQL field like a regular expression

Tags: mysql

I want to add some value in a mysql field (please note i don't want to append). For example my data looks like:

```
+------------+---------------+
|    col1    |    value      |
+------------+---------------+
| DCM4CHEE01 | "aaaa","bbbb" | 
| DCM4CHEE01 | "xxxx","yyyy" | 
+------------+---------------+
```

I want to add a piece to string to the value field (not append) like:

```
+------------+-------------------+
|    col1    |       value       |
+------------+-------------------+
| DCM4CHEE01 | "aaaa","bbbb-mgr" | 
| DCM4CHEE01 | "xxxx","yyyy-mgr" | 
+------------+-------------------+
```

I want to replace the last occurance of **"** with **-mgr"**. How can I achieve this by running one single mysql query?

Comment: I don't think there is a boiler plate way of doing this with MySQL.  Why are you storing your `value` column as CSV?  You should consider normalizing your database and keeping it relational.

Answer (score 0):

use `INSERT`

```
INSERT('"aaaa","bbbb"', length('"aaaa","bbbb"'), 5, '-mgr"')
```

Comment: I think this will replace -mgr with an empty string. my requirement is to add -mgr.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
select concat(left('"aaaa","bbbb"',length('"aaaa","bbbb"') -1),'-mgr"')
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/014de/135)**

I am aware that it is not using Replace but I think this is a better way of achieving what you are asking. If you want to update all column then it will be like

```
UPDATE mytable
SET value =concat(left(value ,length(value) -1),'-mgr"')
```